# Hash Function not correct? Math.pow does not handle arbitrarily large numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this [easy problem](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/hash-function/) on LintCode and I have my solution:

```
import math
class Solution:
    """
    @param key: A String you should hash
    @param HASH_SIZE: An integer
    @return an integer
    """
    def hashCode(self, key, HASH_SIZE):
        # write your code here
        ret=0
        for i in range(0,len(key)):
            multiplier=int(math.pow(33,len(key)-i-1))
            ret += (multiplier* ord(key[i]))
        return ret%HASH_SIZE
```

But it only works for keys of `length <= 11` and does not work otherwise (wrong answer). Python handles arbitrarily large numbers by default, so what is the problem ? This is so simple and getting it wrong is driving me crazy.

The description of problem reads:

> In data structure Hash, hash function is used to convert a string(or
>   any other type) into an integer smaller than hash size and bigger or
>   equal to zero. The objective of designing a hash function is to "hash"
>   the key as unreasonable as possible. A good hash function can avoid
>   collision as less as possible. A widely used hash function algorithm
>   is using a magic number 33, consider any string as a 33 based big
>   integer like follow:
>
> ```
> hashcode("abcd") = (ascii(a) * 333 + ascii(b) * 332 + ascii(c) *33 +
> ascii(d)) % HASH_SIZE 
>
>                           = (97* 333 + 98 * 332 + 99 * 33 +100) % HASH_SIZE
>
>                           = 3595978 % HASH_SIZE
> ```
>
> here HASH_SIZE is the capacity of the hash table (you can assume a
>   hash table is like an array with index 0 ~ HASH_SIZE-1).
>
> Given a string as a key and the size of hash table, return the hash
>   value of this key.f

**Update:** Rob's answer solves the issue of incorrect answer, but now speed is an issue.

**Update2:**
Both of the following techniques worked:

```
        ret=0
        ## technique 1
        for i in range(0,len(key)):
            multiplier= pow(33,(len(key)-i-1),HASH_SIZE)
            ret += (multiplier * ord(key[i]))
        return ret%HASH_SIZE
        # technique 2
        ret=0
        multiplier = 1
        for ch in key[::-1]:
            ret = (ret + ord(ch) * multiplier) % HASH_SIZE
            multiplier = (multiplier * 33) % HASH_SIZE
        return ret % HASH_SIZE
```

Comment: Please provide details on "does not work"; that's hardly a problem description.  Show us input and response for a few good & bad cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pair of facts that will lead you to a solution:

1. The `pow(x, y, [z])` builtin function will accurately calculate `(x ** y) % z` without involving arbitrary-length integers.
2. `(a + b + …) % x` is the same as `(a%x + b%x + …) % x`. (That is, you can perform modulus operations within the sum without affecting the result.)

Comment: Not on its own, but knowing that will help you use `pow()` effectively.

Answer (score 3):

> > Python handles arbitrarily large numbers by default

Yes, it does, but only integers are arbitrarily large. `math.pow()` deals in floats, which do have a size limit.

Try:

```
#UNTESTED
multiplier=33**(len(key)-i-1)
```

Comment: Even if Python ints are arbitrarily large, that doesn't mean it's a good idea to *let them* get arbitrarily large.

Comment: Okay that works but for a long key, it exceeds the time limit. What can be done to speed up the calculation?

Comment: Rewrite your algorithm. Consider how you can avoid calling the exponentiation function altogether.

Comment: Here is one possible solution: [spoiler alert](http://ideone.com/tMMCtM).